# Помощь в регулярке PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно составить регулярное выражение для `preg_match`, которое искало бы все символы кроме `A-Za-zА-я0-9` и `-` (тире). Именно в тире состоит вся сложность.

Comment: `[^-A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]` и после выражения не забыть `u` что бы юникод т.е. русские символы понимало. А знак тире может быть первым в скобках. ну либо экранировать его обратной косой, которую скорее всего придется писать дважды в php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя модификатор `i` ([PCRE_CASELESS](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)) можно получить и более короткий вариант:

```
/[^0-9a-zа-яё\-]/ui
```

Answer (score 1):

Тире надо ставить в начало или конец набора. А ещё ты забыл Ё. И посадил баг в виде `А-я`.

```
[^-A-Za-zА-ЯЁа-яё0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью комментария под этим постом, нашел решение. 
Конечный вариант: `preg_match('/[^\-A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]/u', $param);`

Comment: Ваше регулярное выражение не учитывает букву `Ё`